# UK CGT on selling rental property

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

I bought a property for £235,000 in 2013. I'm hopefully selling the property soon for about £325,000.

I lived in the property between 2013-2015. During this period the property grew in value to £300,000.

Over the next 4 years, I rented the property. The property has only grown in value £25,000 during this period.

Can I pay tax on only the £25,000? or do I have to spread the overall growth of the property equally amongst periods of residency and rental?

Answer (score 6):

> **Can I pay tax on only the £25,000?**

No. you can claim some relief on CGT but you don't get to specify what gains occurred in what years.

You get relief on a proportion of *overall* capital gain based on the ratio of time that was your main home to total years owned.

You can't get relief on more than one property.

See https://www.gov.uk/tax-relief-selling-home/y/yes/no/no/yes

Answer (score 2):

I will add to the answer by @RedGrittyBrick that if you lived in a house, you get 18 months of exemption from capital gains tax "for free". So if you live in a house for 6 months, you are exempt from capital gains tax for a proportion of 2 years of the time you owned the house, for example.

I will also add that if you complete before the end of this tax year (5th of April 2019), I think you qualify for Lettings Relief as you have lived in the house yourself as well has having let it out.